# Huge difference after changing a fraction to decimal

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I have a limit to calculate.

```
With[{p = 1/2, q = 0.1}, 
Limit[a^q Integrate[Sin[x]/x^p, {x, a, Infinity}], a -> Infinity]]
```

gives correct result `0`. But change that $\frac{1}{2}$ to $0.5$,

```
With[{p = 0.5, q = 0.1}, 
Limit[a^q Integrate[Sin[x]/x^p, {x, a, Infinity}], a -> Infinity]]
```

gives `ComplexInfinity` which very far away from the correct answer. Why does machine precision and infinite precision have this huge difference without any warning?

FYI, for any decimal p, using decimal gives incorrect result, while the true value is 0.

Comment: The difference seems to lie in the integration; when `p == 1/2` the integral is expressed as a function of `FresnelS`; in the numerical case of `p == 0.5`, instead, the integral is expressed with `HypergeometricPFQ`. Unfortunately I don't know enough about special functions to go any further than that, but others on this site do, so hopefully they may be able to weigh in on this.

Comment: Seems like a possible bug to me. This integral looks convergent to me for any `p>q` regardless, machine or infinite precision.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Mathematica gives a result for the integral. Then claims the limit diverges for decimal input. No bug there.

Comment: Well...`1.000000000001^n/1.^n` and `.9999999999999^n/1.^n` also have very different behaviors as `n` gets large. The differing forms of integral strike me as being similar in spirit to this situation.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau the integral should have a convergent, though not necessarily 0 result for all `p>0`. The limit as a whole, though I have not taken the time to rigorously prove this, should reduce to zero for `a -> Infinity` and `p>q`. If there was a case, that only *exactly* `1/2` works, while otherwise some important condition is not met, I would agree with you, but IMO here the result should be zero for a range of `p`s.

Comment: Possibly shows a bug in `Series` handling of `HypergeometricPFQ` at infinity, when input to PFQ is approximate.